# How to make text to not overlap outer containers in responsive header(flexbox)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm trying to make a responsive header which will look Ok on most screen resolutions(width:320-1920px) with minimum usage of media queries:
[image]

But when I shrink width enough, text starts to overlap outer containers:
[image]

First thought was to use `overflow: hidden;` on `li` elements but it doesn't look any better:
[image]

Here's the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hardcore/hxgbk6m0/1/

When borders of `li` elements start touching text, I would like it to stop shrinking, so text doesn't overlap borders of `li` elements. Text length can change, so I can't just set static min-width. I would also like height to stop shrinking as well when horizontal borders reach text, so menu items are always squares.

How can I do that? Is that even possible using CSS only without using JavaScript? I've spent few hours trying to do that and it seems like I can't do it by myself. Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the width off of your buttons or Div and use padding-right and padding left. This will allow the button or div to size as the page moves, and will keep the same space on each side of the text.

```
.className{
padding-right:1%;
padding-left:1%;
}
```

other than that you will have to change the font size with a @media query.